# What are the best practices for node.js?

Tags: node.js

I've been coding in node for a while, and often I wonder if the way I'm doing things are right/efficient. I'm sure there are many like me, so it would be awesome if experienced coders can enlighten us with some general node.js best practices. Thanks!

Comment: Write clean, well commented code.

Comment: I'd also be interested to hear some answers to that. Like how to structure code, how to deal with deep callback nesting, how to use classes, etc.

Comment: Testing... https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#testing

Comment: Read Felix's node.js style guide. It answers a lot of little questions you might have about best practices. If you haven't already, read Crockford's Javascript: The good parts. It's packed with best practices for javascript.

Comment: i would have liked for this not to be closed :(